# Java class inheritance organization

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm having a hard time finding what I need, and figuring out how to ask for it so please consider this:

```
public class Environment {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Operations op = new Operations();

    public Environment(){
        Operations.changeSuper();
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Operations extends Environment {
    public void changeSuper(){
        x++;
        y--;
    }
}
```

This is a simple representation of what I have attempted already. However I dont think that initializing Operations in Environment correct, as it causes the constructor to loop. But if I dont, then I get null pointer when I attempt to call changeSuper().

Is this the correct way to use extends? Whould there be a better way to abstract the methods from the class file.

Long story short, I want to move methods out of a class file, but still allow them to affect it's local variables

Comment: Your code will not compile. `changeSuper` is an instance method, while you are calling it as a *static*, at `Operations.changeSuper()`. If you are interested in runtime behavior, make sure your code compiles before posting it as question.

Comment: The code I have provided is not literal, I provided it as a simple explanation of what I have done. So far it compiles, but wont run

Comment: The above code will not compile.

Comment: Why don't you say what you are trying to *accomplish,* instead of just posting your non-working solution?

Comment: "I'm having a hard time finding what I need, and figuring out how to ask for it so please consider this:"

Comment: "What you need" in order to do _what_, exactly?

Comment: Please consider what? It would be easier on everybody if you started at the beginning, not the end.

Comment: I was quoting the first line of my post where I stated that I was unsure of what to ask. Then added my best attempt at the end of my question

Comment: OK: "I want to move methods out of a class file, but still allow them to affect it's local variables". *Why?* This is counter to everything we have learned about encapsulation over the last 30 yeras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment` isn't an `Operations`.. so no.
Sounds like you need composition. And you should make your class `Operation` not `Operations`.

So have something like so:

```
public class Environment {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Operation op ;

    public Environment(){
         op=new Operation(this);

    }

    public void changeEnvironment() {}
    public void incrementX(){}
    public void incrementY() {}
}
```

and:

```
public class Operation   {
    Environment e;
    public Operation(Environment e){
        this.e = e;
        e.incrementX();
        e.decrementY();
    }
    public void changeEnvironment()
    {   
       e.changeEnvironment() ;
    }
}
```

If the changes is done only in `Environment`, then it makes maintaining easier, also preserving encapsulation.

Comment: I hadn't considered that before. Will 'e' not just be a copy of the actual class passed by 'this'? Meaning that when the changeSuper method has finished the values will be lost and Environment will remain unchanged?

Comment: It is a copy of the reference. So the actual Environment object in memory gets modified. Sorry, I'm half awake.. I just have this feeling I'm giving you a bad advice :(

Comment: No worries, I feel the same, hence my issue. Thanks, I'll try that out in a bit

Comment: I've edited my answer a little.. hopefully when I wake up tomorrow it won't be a facepalm

Comment: Passing this as a parameter worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer subclass `Operations` in Super Class **through inheritance**. Instead, make `Environment` as as abstract class and define `changeSuper` as abstract method as below:

```
 public abstract class Environment {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    public abstract void changeSuper();

    public Environment(){
     changeSuper();
    }
  }
```

Then define `Operations` class to extend `Environment` and implement `changeSuper()` method as below:

```
  public class Operations  extends Environment {
     @Override
     public void changeSuper(){
           x++;
           y--;
     }
  }
```

Now if you create a `main` method in `Operations` class as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Environment env = new Operations();
    System.out.println("x="+env.x+"&y="+env.y);//<- it will print x=-1&y=-1
}
```

Comment: Im trying to avoid having to override all the methods, the purpose of this is to remove 70 ish methods from the main class

Comment: @RyanS: Its just declaration in the super class and implementation is only in the subclass. No repetition in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that changeSuper should be static.

Comment: wrong! if static, changeSuper will not have access to the environment attributes!

Comment: Sorry, you right, I guess I rushed into conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want Operations to be both

- a subtype of Environment and
- an instance variable of Environment

If Environment is supertype of Operations - they will share non-private instance variables automatically (no need for one to call the other).
If not supertype, it is bad practice to break encapsulation by directly accessing instance variables.

**Try this:**

```
public class Environment {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public Environment(){
    }
}

and:

public class Operations extends Environment {
    public void changeState(){
        x++;
        y--;
    }
}

and:

public class MasterControl {
   Operations op = new Operations();
   op.changeState();
}
```

**Alternatively**

```
public class Environment {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Operations op = new Operations();

    public Environment(){
        op.changeState();
    }

    public int getX() {return x;}
    public setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public setY(int x) {this.y = y;}

}
```

and:

```
public class Operations {
    public void changeState(Environment env){
        env.setX(env.getX+1);
        env.setY(env.getY-1);
    }
}
```

Here Environment has responsibility for storing environment state and making it available to other objects.  Here Operations is carrying out a specialist operation to modify environment state.

Kay?